# RouteEnhancers section in the config.yaml gets deleted when site configuration is saved

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-9.x

I've just had an unfortunate data loss of the the section routeEnhancer after edition the site configuration in the backend. I've noticed the backend doesn't reflect the data in that section at all, but I certainly didn't expect it to just be silently killed off.

Is this "intended" or unfinished or am I doing something wrong?

Here's the contents of my config file.

```
rootPageId: 1
base: 'https://REDACTED2019.dievorschau.de/'
baseVariants: {  }
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: /de/
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: German
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ''
    flag: de
  -
    title: Englisch
    enabled: true
    languageId: '1'
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_GB.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: Englisch
    hreflang: en-GB
    direction: ltr
    fallbackType: strict
    flag: gb
errorHandling: {  }
routes: {  }
routeEnhancers:
  REDACTEDveranstaltungen_veranstaltungen:
    type: Extbase
    extension: REDACTEDVeranstaltungen
    plugin: Veranstaltungen
    routes: 
      - { routePath: '/themenbereiche/{thema_titel}', _controller: 'Termin::search',  _arguments: {'thema_titel': 'veranstaltungsarten/0'} }
      - { routePath: '/veranstaltung/{termin_titel}', _controller: 'Veranstaltung::show',  _arguments: {'termin_titel': 'termin'} }
    aspects:
      termin_titel:
        #type: TerminValueMapper
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_REDACTEDveranstaltungen_domain_model_termin'
        routeFieldName: 'uid'
      thema_titel:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'sys_category'
        routeFieldName: 'title'
```

Comment: Can you still reproduce this overwriting of the routeEnhancers in version 9.5.9+? Because I just reused an existing configuration file containing routeEnhancers and then made some changes in the sites modules and saved and it did not overwrite the routeEnhancers. My file looks very similar to yours. It is very simple, not using any imports.

Comment: @SybillePeters To be honest I can't. The installation is, for now, still at 9.5.7. Will update to the latest release before the end of the week and get back at you.

Comment: @SybillePeters TYPO3 indeed now seems to parse the yaml file correctly and writes it back into the file when saving. Line indentation and inline arrays written differently, but other than that, intact and complete. \o/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, indeed your SiteConfiguration will be overwritten even you edit and save it from backend for any given page-tree.

In one of my latest project I used the import function for yaml SiteConfiguration.
My default yaml looks like

```
imports:
- { resource: "EXT:my_custom_sitepackage/Configuration/Routes/Default.yaml" }
```

In this case you are able to keep your configuration stored and versionized within your custom sitepackage.
In case of any backend editor would change it via TYPO3 backend as you mentioned, you are able to recreate the former configuration by restore the default yaml file.

But it does not solves the issue, that whole installation could be broken in such a case, where an editor/admin edit and save SiteConfiguration via backend, until you restore your default yaml file manually.

I would like to have the possibility to keep any predefined configuration permanent loaded as described here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86803

Comment: Today a patch was merged into TYPO3 core, "that only modified values are written
and imports are completely left as they are".
https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/61573/